# Deep observables and foreach templates

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model like this:

```
function viewModel() {
   this.a = ko.observable();
}
```

At some point I try to do this (where `m` is my `viewModel`):

```
m.a(new thing());
```

Now, I have a template binding like this:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 't', foreach: a().b }"></ul>
```

But it will crash before anything happens because `a()` is initially `undefined` or `null`. So I tried this variation:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 't', foreach: a.b }"></ul>
```

But this is weird, because now it doesn't crash but renders a single empty item, using the template `t` and that's wrong.

I'm a bit at loss here, I thought the point was that I would be able to defined the source (like this) and as things changed it would just update stuff but I'm just getting errors (or nothing is happening) what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can protect yourself from hitting an undefined property by writing your binding like this:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 't', foreach: a() ? a().b : [] }"></ul>
```

Otherwise, you can push this concern to your view model and create a dependentObservable like:

```
viewModel.c = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.a() ? this.a().b : [];
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: Immediately after posting I discovered that it does work with a `dependentObservable` so I'm using that atm. I thought about using an expression but couldn't see how that would work with bindings so I ruled it out. Do you know if this is a requirement though? That if you have deep observables `a.b` then the right-hand side has to be dependent? Ah, this doesn't make much sense. I shouldn't be short circuiting stuff in the view model like this...

Comment: Ideally, you would wrap your "a" functionality in a template.  Then, call that template `<div data-bind="template: { name: 'aTmpl', data: 'a' }"></div>`.  If `a` is null, then it will not get rendered.  Inside of the template, you can freely use `b`.

Comment: In KO 1.3, you will be able to use the control-flow bindings to make this even easier like:  `<div data-bind="with: a"><ul data-bind="foreach: b"><li>...</li></ul></div>`